# Active Directory : How to get Group information that belongs to another domain?

Tags: windows, active-directory, cross-domain

I have a User1 in Domain1 which belongs to a group Group1.

Group1 belongs to a different domain Domain2.

Using the `memberof` attribute, I can easily see that User1 belongs to Group1.
 But `memberof` only gives me the values of OU and the domains which the group belongs.

**e.g.**

```
CN=Groupname,OU=ou1,DC=Domain1,DC=Domain2,DC=com
```

Does Domain1 store other information of Group1?
 
If yes how can I get sid or guid or any other information of the Group1 without connecting to Domain2?

Edit:

Both the domains are in trust relationship.

Comment: Are those domains in a trust relationship with one another?

Comment: Yes, They are. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get also the SID and GUID by the "Extended DN" LDAP extended control.

Please check:

[How to get AD user's 'memberof' property value in terms of objectGUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105361/how-to-get-ad-users-memberof-property-value-in-terms-of-objectguid/27109511#27109511)

Comment: How to use this control? Do I need to instal them?

Comment: It's built-in since windows 2000. How do you access the AD? script? C#?

Comment: Do I need to mention these control in search filter?

Comment: The search filter remains the same. In general to use the control you will have to provide the OID of the LDAP extended control plus some settings for the control. But I have no knowledge on Talend, not sure how to do that.